# Adding TestSuite to a twisted program

Tags: python, eclipse, twisted

I am trying to add more tests to a home automation system I am working on http://github.com/DBrianKimmel/Pyhouse.  I use Eclipse (Luna) for development and testing.  There are a fair number of Python packages with many modules each.  Some packages are nested 3 or 4 deep.  I am now trying to get testing to work from a higher level than one module at a time.  I have read the python and twisted documentation but I am at a loss for getting the aggregate testing to work within Eclipse.  I would appreciate any pointers or references on how to make this work.

### Clarification

Eclipse has a feature that allows one to run unit tests.  I develop and test entirely within Eclipse, typically I have 4 or more tabs open where I work.  One is the module I am working on and another is the unit test for that module.  Quite often I need references to the development module so they are in open tabs.  I consider Eclipse essential to my development so the final solution must operate in Eclipse.

I have tried a number of approaches and the latest is this.  Here is the module test:

```
# Import system type stuff
from twisted.trial import unittest

# Import PyMh files and modules.
from Modules.Families.Insteon import Insteon_utils

ADDR_DR_SLAVE_MSG = bytearray(b'\x16\xc9\xd0')
ADDR_DR_SLAVE_INT = 1493456
ADDR_NOOK_MSG = bytearray(b'\x17\xc2\x72')
ADDR_NOOK_INT = 1557106

MSG_50 = bytearray(b'\x02\x50\x16\xc9\xd0\x1b\x47\x81\x27\x09\x00')
MSG_62 = bytearray(b'\x02\x62\x17\xc2\x72\x0f\x19\x00\x06')

class C01_Conversions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.inst = Insteon_utils
        pass

    def test_01_message2int(self):
        result = self.inst.message2int(MSG_50, 2)
        self.assertEqual(result, ADDR_DR_SLAVE_INT)
        result = self.inst.message2int(MSG_62, 2)
        self.assertEqual(result, ADDR_NOOK_INT)

    def test_02_int2message(self):
        l_msg = MSG_50
        result = self.inst.int2message(ADDR_DR_SLAVE_INT, l_msg, 2)
        self.assertEqual(result[2:5], ADDR_DR_SLAVE_MSG)
        l_msg = MSG_62
        result = self.inst.int2message(ADDR_NOOK_INT, l_msg, 2)
        self.assertEqual(result[2:5], ADDR_NOOK_MSG)

def suite():
    l_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    l_suite.addTest(C01_Conversions('test_01_message2int', 'test_02_int2message'))
    return l_suite
```

And here is the aggregating module:

```
# Import system type stuff
from twisted.trial import unittest, reporter, runner

# Future modules that need importing
# Import PyMh files and modules.
# from Modules.Families.Insteon.test import \
#        test_Insteon_decoder, test_Insteon_device, test_Insteon_PLM, \
#        test_Insteon_utils, \
#        test_Insteon_xml
from Modules.Families.Insteon import test as I_test


class C99_Family(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.m_test = runner.TestLoader()

    def test_9999_Insteon(self):
        l_package = runner.TestLoader().loadPackage(I_test)
        l_ret = reporter.Reporter()
        l_package.run(l_ret)
        l_ret.done()
        print('9999 Insteon', l_ret)
        l_ret.printErrors()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question really doesn't have enough information to answer sensibly.  What did you try?  What about it didn't work?  What does Eclipse have to do with this?  What is "aggregate" testing?

Comment: I added the clarification section to the question.